# Is there a way to find a specific string in an xml file and then replace the next string underneath it with a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is this possible? I need to edit the following xml file. For every "BASerialKeyND", I need to replace the 987654321 right underneath it. Same thing for "BASerialKey" and 98-7654-321. I cannot count the lines in the file and assign it to a variable and then replace those specific lines because BASerialKeyND and BASerialKey occur on  different lines in different files.

Thanks so much for your help!!!!!!!!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializableDictionary>
    <item>
        <key>BASerialKeyND</key>
        <value>987654321</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>BASerialKey</key>
        <value>98-7654-321</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>MACHINETYPE</key>
        <value>Max</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>PC1NAME</key>
        <value>987654321PC1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>PC2NAME</key>
        <value>987654321PC2</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>REPORTPRINTER</key>
        <value>None</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>PC1PRINTERS</key>
        <value>Name=Microsoft XPS Document Writer

</SerializableDictionary>
```

Comment: Google for `xslt command line`.

Comment: Basically, I just need to change the numbers between <value></value>, but only for the first 2 <value></value> under BASerialKeyND and BASerialKey, not all of them in the file.

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "(<key>BASerialKey(ND)?</key>\s*<value>).*?(</value>)" "$txt=$1+($2?'newValue1':'newValue2')+$3" /m /jq /f "file.xml|utf-8|nb" /o -`